# 405 StatusCode from PUT or DELETE on ASP.Net Core 2.0 in IIS

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core

There are a lot of posts here about this problem, but none of them seem to work for us.  We get a 405 status code from a dotnet 2.0 application only from IIS.  We built the same application and targeted Ubuntu 16.04 with no issues.

The popular fix appears to be to alter the web.config file and add the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules>
          <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
         etc.....
```

However, this causes a 500 internal server error.

We also tried:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
         <remove name="WebDAV"/>
  etc......
```

And this results in the same 405 Status Code.
We also tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs allowUnlisted="false">
          <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
   etc...
```

This also failed.
We tried building the app for .net Core 1.1 with no joy as well (checked to see if a .Core version is the problem).

After each change we did a command line

```
iisreset
```

to make sure that any "in memory" cached settings were cleared.  We also tried rebooting the server each time.

All of these attempts fail.... we still get a 405.

We are pretty sure this is an IIS issue since the app runs fine on Ubuntu, but our production server farm is all Win / IIS so we MUST get this working.

My pending workaround is to code our controllers with NO DELETE or PUT verbs; changing everything to GET and POST.

Anyone else able to crack this nut?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check why trying to remove `WebDAVModule` from web.config throws an error.

Comment: We saw nothing in any logs to indicate why we got the 500, so we did not chase that thread any further.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why, but we deleted the instance of IIS on the server and reinstalled it with ONLY the dotnet core handler.

The site now works as expected.